# .composer directory created on home

Tags: permissions, home-directory, composer

I'm using composer and while I installed global package it will point to `/home/.config/composer` directory (which is normal). While this morning, suddenly in my home there's a directory named `.composer` with lock symbol (root permission). I wonder, how could this happen? It is not a normal folder because I can't directly delete it without root permission. I also never run `sudo composer` command. So, anyone can explain to me what causes this?